# invalid imagelist index - Delphi XE8

Tags: android, delphi, ide, delphi-xe8

While working with Delphi XE8 multi-device app (android), this error keeps popping up: 'Invalid ImageList Index'.

Details:

```
[507A7424]{vcl220.bpl  } Vcl.ImgList.TCustomImageList.Delete (Line 664, "Vcl.ImgList.pas" + 2) + $1C
[0CC0E98C]{MultidevicePreview220.bpl} DesignPreviewFrm.TfrmDesignPreview.UpdateThumb (Line 744, "DesignPreviewFrm.pas" + 50) + $8
[0CC0E597]{MultidevicePreview220.bpl} DesignPreviewFrm.TfrmDesignPreview.TickTackTimer (Line 653, "DesignPreviewFrm.pas" + 27) + $7
[5073D11F]{vcl220.bpl  } Vcl.ExtCtrls.TTimer.Timer (Line 3093, "Vcl.ExtCtrls.pas" + 1) + $E
[5073D003]{vcl220.bpl  } Vcl.ExtCtrls.TTimer.WndProc (Line 3051, "Vcl.ExtCtrls.pas" + 4) + $7
[50172D80]{rtl220.bpl  } System.Classes.StdWndProc (Line 16882, "System.Classes.pas" + 8) + $0
[507CB41F]{vcl220.bpl  } Vcl.Forms.TApplication.ProcessMessage (Line 10352, "Vcl.Forms.pas" + 23) + $1
[507CB462]{vcl220.bpl  } Vcl.Forms.TApplication.HandleMessage (Line 10382, "Vcl.Forms.pas" + 1) + $4
[507CB795]{vcl220.bpl  } Vcl.Forms.TApplication.Run (Line 10520, "Vcl.Forms.pas" + 26) + $3
```

There is no imagelist used in the unit. In fact, the only component is a button.

EDIT: This happens mostly in design mode and has nothing to do with my code. Might be a bug in the IDE.

Comment: Why is the vcl library linked in an android app?

Comment: @LURD This is an IDE exception - I get this too. But I only get it when switching to/from remote desktop. The Delphi IDE itself is VCL. Always fixed by restarting IDE.

Comment: Have you by chance disabled Castalia?

Comment: You should edit your question to make it clear that this is an IDE exception and not an exception in your own code. (Not everyone will notice the `DesignPreviewFrm.TfrmDesignPreview` and realize it's an IDE window.) This would appear to be a bug in the IDE, and if you can create a small MCVE that will allow it to be reproduced it should be reported to Embarcadero as such.

Comment: I take that as a no on the Castalia question? Because I was suspecting me disabling it may have been responsible. And how about the remote desktop? Do you use that? You should really follow-up in the comments if you really want us to help you figure this out. Besides that, as Ken said, you really should report this to Embarcadero.

Comment: The Castalia is on default setting, though after reading your comment, I have tried enabling and disabling it with no changes. Usually,the  error happens when the platform is set to Android.

Comment: I am not using remote desktop. App are being installed directly on my android phone. Again, not a castalia thing (/NOCASTALIA).

Answer (score 2):

1) Close Studio, ensure that the process "bds.exe" is not exists in the tast manager.

2) Go to the folder "C:\Program Files\Embarcadero\Studio\x.0\bin", looking for the file "MultidevicePreview240.bpl".

3) Rename it to "!MultidevicePreview240.bpl"

4) Run Studio and test.

another variant:

The trouble in one of TImage in a TLayout. Fully delete TLayout, add this one and image again — the problem should disappear.